# Persistent (push-based) communication with HTTP

Tags: http, persistent-connection

Consider the following diagram ([source](https://www.8bitmen.com/linkedin-real-time-architecture-how-does-linkedin-identify-its-users-online/)). The diagram describes an **HTTP Push model** with multiple events **pushed** to the client over a persistent connection.

1. How does one establish a persistent connection in HTTP?
2. How could the server **push** events to the client over this connection? To my knowledge, only the client (e.g. browser) can initiate **HTTP requests**.

I can see this working with a WebSocket (full-duplex long-lived connections) but to my knowledge, they don't go over HTTP.

[image]

Comment: Web sockets or server-side events…

Comment: It’s even mentioned in the paragraph above that diagram…!

Comment: @deceze I'm confused. Websockets don't go over HTTP, do they? From Wikipedia: _"WebSocket is distinct from HTTP. Both protocols are located at layer 7 in the OSI model and depend on TCP at layer 4."_

Comment: @Josh I would agree that technically websocket is _not_ HTTP but it does use HTTP for the initial handshake. It is probably be the best solution out there, but if you want HTTP alone then only server-side events kind of qualifies. Even there I would argue that server-side events are kind of a hack on top of HTTP, it works with HTTP but it kind of abuses the intent.

Comment: A lot of 'kind ofs' in my comment, but these are subtle differences. Since you're asking about HTTP on a conceptual level, not 'how do I solve this problem'. If you just want to push events, use websockets.

Comment: Thanks @Evert That's helpful, but then, when using websockets, one is only using HTTP for the initial handshake, and not really establishing a _"persistent HTTP connection"_  for _"HTTP push"_ communication per se, right? In other words, it's not really a HTTP-push connection, since the server can't really send a HTTP request per se to the browser, and HTTP doesn't contemplate any other way of doing this, correct? If that's the case, these clarifications can be the answer by the way.

Comment: Yes, I would say you are right. There is another concept called HTTP/2 Push, but these are also not really server-sent events. If you're just looking to get an answer to the question: Is this comic-sans screenshot technically correct? I wouldn't call it strictly false, but there is nuance.

Comment: Thanks @Evert Frankly, an answer that lays out everything we discussed clearly is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: In a nutshell, there are different ways to do “push” on the web, some more HTTP than others. The diagram labels them summarily as “HTTP Push”, while the text goes into more detail.